Absolute convergence implies equivalence
I'm currently working through chapter 3 of Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich. I came across this exercise, and I'm currently stuck on part (b).

Show that
(a) if $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}=1+\beta_n$, $n=1,2,\dots$, and the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\beta_n$ converges absolutely, then the limit
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=b\in\mathbb{R}$ exists;
(b) if $\frac{a_n}{\alpha_{n+1}}=1+\frac{p}{n}+\alpha_n$,
$n=1,2,\dots$, and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n$ converges
absolutely, then $a_n\sim\frac{c}{n^p}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$;
(c) if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is such that
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1+\frac{p}{n}+\alpha_n$ and the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n$ converges absolutely, then
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely for $p>1$ and diverges
for $p\leq 1$ (Gauss' test for absolute convergence of a series).

I haven't been able to make much headway, and so far I've only got $a_n=\alpha_{n+1}(1+\frac{p}{n}+\alpha_n)$ which doesn't make much difference. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.
